# Using Notepad++ to write Python scripts for ArcGIS Pro

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ and I have set the "RUN" command to use the ArcGIS Pro Python executable located at "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe"

Once I hit Run, however, I get the following message:

```
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment see https://conda.io/activation
```

When I went to that website, it told me to run c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base. I do not have that directory.

What should I do to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/using-conda-with-arcgis-pro.htm):

> C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\scripts\propy.bat my_script.py

But you could also switch to a code editor/IDE that understands conda environments like VS Code or PyCharm.